# Automatic Sphinx delta indexing

Tags: sphinx

I'm looking for suggestions on how to automate my indexing, how could I keep a record of which rows have been indexed? Once I sort that out I just need to use cron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main docs has an example...

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-2.0.6.html#delta-updates

Using a special counter table...

Comment: For future reference, the most current manual: http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#delta-updates